# Magento 2 add to cart performance issue

Tags: checkout, addtocart, performance, slow-response

In my Magento 2 website adding to cart takes about 10 sec.
Caching is OK. Redis is configured. Merging/minimizing for CSS/JS is enabled.
I'm noticed that after first adding an item to the cart, adding to cart of this item takes a few seconds (Looks like caching), but after 5 minutes it's taking too much time again. Maybe there is a way to reduce time or cache "add to cart" for a long time?
Great thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: do you have some custom extensions loaded / processed in checkout?

Comment: No. I have only a custom theme.